# Running a neural network backwards

Tags: python, ai, neural-network, pytorch

I've [read this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901) where they basically run a network backwards.

And decided to try. Luckily, many useful functions are implemented already in pytorch.

The main idea is this:

1. Write a convnet
2. Write a reverse convnet
3. Attach hooks to all layers and extract what we need
4. Train the convnet
5. Run the reverse net as well to see what information it retrieves.

I'd love criticism in the idea, and the code in a high level (especially the architecture and design idea.) and which changes or approaches you'd do instead.

The nets are:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn.functional import conv_transpose2d
from base_types import KeyKeyTensor, KeyTensor


class Backbone(nn.Module):
    """
    Set of conv-batchNorm-maxpool-relu blocks
    Args: None
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=2)
        self.batch1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(3, 3), return_indices=True)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=2)
        self.batch2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=2)
        self.batch3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()

        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=2)
        self.batch4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
        self.maxpool4 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(3, 3), return_indices=True)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()

        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=2)
        self.batch5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.relu5 = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.batch1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x, _ = self.maxpool1(x)  # we are using it for deconvolve.
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.batch2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.batch3(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = self.batch4(x)
        x = self.relu4(x)
        x, _ = self.maxpool4(x)  # same
        x = self.conv5(x)
        x = self.batch5(x)
        x = self.relu5(x)
        return x


class InvertedBackbone(Backbone):
    """
    Set of relu-conv-UnPool blocks (not using batch norm here.)
    Args: None
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxupool1 = nn.MaxUnpool2d(kernel_size=(3, 3))
        self.maxupool4 = nn.MaxUnpool2d(kernel_size=(3, 3))

    def forward(
        self,
        layer_kernels: KeyTensor,
        layer_indices: KeyKeyTensor,
        layer_activations: KeyTensor,
    ) -> torch.Tensor:
        input = layer_activations["last_layer"]
        x = self.relu(input)
        x = conv_transpose2d(x, layer_kernels["backbone.conv5"])
        upooldata = layer_indices["backbone.maxpool4"]
        x = self.maxupool4(x, upooldata["tensor"], output_size=upooldata["inputSize"])
        x = conv_transpose2d(x, layer_kernels["backbone.conv4"])
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = conv_transpose2d(x, layer_kernels["backbone.conv3"])
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = conv_transpose2d(x, layer_kernels["backbone.conv2"])
        x = self.relu(x)
        upool1data = layer_indices["backbone.maxpool1"]
        x = self.maxupool1(x, upool1data["tensor"], output_size=upool1data["inputSize"])
        x = conv_transpose2d(x, layer_kernels["backbone.conv1"])
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x
```

The basic hook usage:

```
import torch
from operator import attrgetter
from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import get_graph_node_names
from nn_arch import ClassifierV2 as ClassificationNN
from base_types import KeyKeyTensor, KeyTensor

# define the hooks
layer_activations: KeyTensor = {}
layer_kernels: KeyTensor = {}
layer_pools: KeyKeyTensor = {}


def get_pooling_indices(layer_name: str):
    def hook(model, input, output):
        layer_pools[layer_name] = {"tensor": output[1], "inputSize": input[0].size()}

    return hook


def get_activation():
    def hook(model, input, output):
        if isinstance(output, tuple):
            layer_activations["last_layer"] = output[0]
        else:
            layer_activations["last_layer"] = output

    return hook


def make_hooks(model: ClassificationNN) -> tuple[KeyTensor, KeyKeyTensor, KeyTensor]:
    train_nodes, _ = get_graph_node_names(model)
    train_nodes = list(filter(lambda x: "backbone" in x, train_nodes))
    for i, node in enumerate(train_nodes):
        print(node)
        if i == len(train_nodes) - 1:
            attrgetter(node)(model).register_forward_hook(get_activation())
        elif "maxpool" in node:
            attrgetter(node)(model).register_forward_hook(get_pooling_indices(node))
        elif "conv" in node:
            layer_kernels[node] = attrgetter(node)(model).weight

    return layer_kernels, layer_pools, layer_activations
```

Currently this is what I get (I made a gif out of the pictures from the backward-run), there isn't much of a difference between epochs, apart from a few ones more black.

This network achieves 99% accuracy for the task though, which is classifying rotated images.

[image]